# Django - Get objects which do NOT have any related objects

Tags: python, mysql, django

This may be a duplicate.

So I have:

```
class User(models.Model):
    school = models.ForeignKey(School)

class Staff(User):
    ...

class Student(User):
    ...

class Placement(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student)
    
class Visit(models.Model):
    placement = models.ForeignKey(Placement)
    staff = models.ForeignKey(Staff)
```

And I want to retrieve all Placements which do not have any Visits (and the Student belongs to a particular School).

My views

```
def placements(request):
    if request.session['utype'] == 't':
    context['user'] = Staff.objects.get(pk=request.session['user'])
    if request.method == 'POST':
        placements = context['placements'] = Placement.objects.filter(student__school=school)
        for choice in visits:
            placement = Placement.objects.get(pk=choice)
            visit = placement.NewVisit(user, placement.date, '', False)
            visit.save()
        return redirect('workxp:visits')
    else:
        context['placements'] = Placement.objects.filter(student__school=school, visit_set=None)
    return render(request, 'workxp/staff/placements.html', context)
```

This is what I have so far from looking at other questions, but it doesn't seem to work...

```
no_visits = Placement.objects.filter(student__school=school_object, visit_set=None)
```

If I give a related name to the placement field in Visit, it works. Why not visit_set?

Comment: Are you sure that `visit` is the name of the reverse lookup field? You might want to read the Django docs on that one. (I always specify a reverse name for this very reason-- I usually don't like what Django picks)

Comment: No it's not haha. I was looking at some others and I think I just used the normal name instead of specifying like you say.

Answer (score 7):

You need to use `visit_set` to reference the reverse relation since it's one to many

```
no_visits = Placement.objects.filter(student__school=school_object, visit_set=None)
```

or if you were to specify a nice related name...

```
class Visit(models.Model):
    placement = models.ForeignKey(Placement, related_name='visits')
    ...

no_visits = Placement.objects.filter(student__school=school_object, visits=None)
```

Comment: Not exactly. I've added all the code that I think would be relevant.